# Need to arrange the displaying pattern in table view controller Xcode 7 using Firebase

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, controller

I have created a table view controller which populates the cell from firebase.  The table loads perfectly with a minor problem. Whenever a new item is added the item get displayed at the bottom of the screen instead on the top.  How do I arrange my item, so that whenever a new item is added, it gets on the top cell and get displayed on the top of the app not on the bottom so I don't have to scroll down to see what new item has been added..

Comment: sample code might be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Firebase doesn't have a natural order - you need to decide how you want your data ordered and set up your structure accordingly. Then retrieve the data by that order. You can order them by their keys, values or priority.

For example:

You have a blog app and you always want the the blogs listed in time order:

```
post_0
   timestamp: 1
   post: "posted at 1am"
post_1
   timeStamp: 13
   post: "posted at 1pm"
post_2
   timeStamp: 9
   post: "posted at 9am"
```

When you read the posts node, order by timeStamp and it will be in that order, 1, 9, 13.

```
ref.queryOrderedByChild("timeStamp").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
    println("\(snapshot.value)")
})
```

If you want just the latest two posts, use a limit query.

```
let scoresRef = Firebase(url:"https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/scores")
postsRef.queryOrderedByValue().queryLimitedToLast(2).observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
    println("post time \(snapshot.value)")
})
```

Of course there are many other options:

- Read the firebase data into an array, then use NSSortDescriptors to sort descending.
- Read the firebase data in via order by (so they are 1, 2, 3, 4) with 4 being the most current post, and insert each one into an array at position 0.

  4 Most current post stored position 0 in the array

  3 <- read after 2

  2 <- read after 1

  1 <- first read in

The [Firebase Reading Data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html) is a really good reference for understanding queries and the ordering of data.